# Retrieve news feed in Facebook Android SDK v4 using graph api

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I am using the following code to generate access token and retrieve some basic fields from user profile. But I want to retrieve news feed, for that I need to use newGraphPathRequest instead of newMeRequest. Please tell me how to do that?

```
loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            // App code


    GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object1,
                                GraphResponse response) {
                            // Application code


                            Log.d("tagpranav1", object1.toString());
                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,link,birthday,email,gender");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();


        }

        @Override

        public void onCancel() {
            // App code
            Log.v("LoginActivity", "cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            // App code
            Log.v("LoginActivity", exception.getCause().toString());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
mFacebookLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newGraphPathRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(), "/me/home", new GraphRequest.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {

                }
            });
        }
```